# Draw a dashed and dotted bezier curve in QML

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, shader, qml

I've seen there is an example implementation of [a Bezier curve in QML](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.1/qtquick/scenegraph-customgeometry.html), but I'm looking for a hint how to implement dashed or dotted bezier curve line. As far as I see, tha authors of Bezier curve example are using `QSGGeometryNode` to store inside `QSGGeometry` with a `QSGFlatColorMaterial` material applied on it. Then they simply create list of points and draw segments between them.

Is it possible to write a `shader` and apply it to `QSGFlatColorMaterial` (to display line as `dashed`, `dotted`, etc)?

Eventually, is it possible to store more than one `QSGGeometry` inside `QSGGeometryNode`?

**UPDATE**

I would like to implement this in "pure `QtQuick`" - not in "old" interfaces (like `QPainter etc`) - because I do not want to use something, which switches context (openGL and CPU). I prefer the solution with custom shader (if is it doable) - because I'll have more possibilities in implementing custom look and feel (dashed, doted, colored, maybe animated etc).

If it is not possible, I'll use `QPainter`.

Comment: It's relatively trivial to alter the Bezier curve example to generate geometry for each of the sub-segments as needed by the selected line style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this task is a good candidate for implementing using `QSGGeometryNode`, it would be much easier to implement it using `QPainter` based drawing and a `QQuickPaintedItem`. You will still get the benefits of OpenGL, since `QPainter` supports GL drawing as well and it is still faster than software. You can use the stock `QPen` with stock dotted or dashed patterns or make your own with a simple `QVector`.

Alternatively, you can go for a custom GL drawing approach instead of using the classes provided by Qt, which are pretty limited when it comes to representing advanced compound geometry. You can even use instancing (if available) to improve performance even further, and just position dashes or dot geometry along the path curve.

Last but not least, you can use a QML Canvas element, which supports pretty much the same operations as `QPainter` and probably offers the same performance.

EDIT: As your update suggests, you missed the part where I said `QPainter` can draw in both software and GL, with GL drawing being often significantly faster. Also, by drawing to a GL context, you don't have to move the framebuffer from CPU to GPU memory, it is kept in GPU memory. So no overhead. As for animations and the other stuff, sure, it is not possible with `QPainter` you are limited to whatever `QPen` provides - different joins, caps and so on can be used to modify the shape to some extent, but no miracles... It won't be possible with shaders too, it will only be possible with custom geometry. And if you use a `QObject` based object for each dash/dot element in order to independently animate them, it will end up quite expenssive, `QObject` is very heavy and should not be used with such light hand. So custom GL rendering to a FBO is pretty much the way to go if you want that kind of flexibility, but you will have to move completely out of the QtQuick API and into GL land.

At any rate, a dashed line shader should not be all that complex, basically you color the fragment based on the distance from the curve and the "period" along its length. I found [this example](http://korkd.com/2012/02/15/dashed-lines/), haven't tried it myself. You could animate the thresholds, even use a sine function to get funky looking styling.

As for a "pure" QtQuick implementation, the API has not really been designed to handle such type of drawing tasks, that is why the Canvas element was provided to fill the gap and get advanced paining functionality from QML/JS. The Canvas is effectively a wrapper around `QPainter` that draws onto a FBO.

In the end it doesn't boil down to what is possible/impossible but which approach makes the most sense and is most efficient at getting the job done. Try the `QQuickPaintedItem` approach first, since it is the easiest, if you are not happy with performance, you can implement another more complex solution and profile against the first. After all, that is why `QQuickPaintedItem` was introduced in the first place - to handle legacy painting that is not convenient to do with the `QQuickItem` class.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I would love to implement this in pure `QtQuick` - I would like not to use `QPainter` - if it is possible. If not I'll use it - see the updated question. If would it be possible to write a shader it would be much more powerfull than using predefined `QPainter` styles.

Comment: It is still a pure QtQuick implementation, `QQuickPaintedItem` as the name suggest is a part of the QtQuick2 API. You can create custom style patters for `QPainter` very easy. I've been wondering about multiple geometry as well, but it doesn't seem the API is capable of this. In the end, it is either `QPainter` or your own rendering to a framebuffer, which you can draw on a rectangle. I suppose a shader is possible but not the most elegant solution to this problem. You may want to look at the `QPainter` code that draws in GL contexts, it uses geometry to draw as well.

Comment: Thank you for all the clarifications! I'm trying to accomplish this task by shader because I want to animate it and it would be easier to do it with shaders. I know the bases of OGL Shaders, so there will be no problem for me to write it. The only problem is how to use it with `QSGFlatColorMaterial` in `QML` - I'll try to find a way, but If you know it, I would be thankful for a hint :)

Comment: Why would you use `QSGFlatColorMaterial` when you can simply pass any flat color uniform to the shader you will write to make the dashed line?

Comment: Ok, so I will not - I'm new to QML and I thought it is a "default" material, which we can apply shaders on. Do you have any simple example showing how such flat color uniform could be used there?

Comment: Flat color shading is literally as simple as setting each fragment to the same color, in the `main` method of the shader you just `gl_FragColor = vec4(R, G, B, A);` (0-1 clamped float values) or a `vec4` you pass as uniform.

Answer (score 4):

With Qt 5.10 the Shape element has been introduced and seems to do exactly what you want.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-shapes-shape.html

```
Shape {
    width: 20
    ShapePath {
        strokeColor: "blue"
        strokeWidth: 2
        strokeStyle: ShapePath.DashLine
        startX: 0
        startY: 0
        PathLine { x: parent.width; y: 0 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use this approach:

[Beziercurve example modified to use QSGVertexColorMaterial](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/32614)

Then, you can specify your color and alpha for each vetex, to get the dashes, dots, or whatever pattern you choose.

Here are the important parts:

```
 geometry = new QSGGeometry(QSGGeometry::defaultAttributes_ColoredPoint2D(), m_segmentCount);
 //geometry = new QSGGeometry(QSGGeometry::defaultAttributes_Point2D(), m_segmentCount);
```

---

```
QSGVertexColorMaterial *material = new QSGVertexColorMaterial;
//material->setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0));
```

---

```
//QSGGeometry::Point2D *vertices = geometry->vertexDataAsPoint2D();
QSGGeometry::ColoredPoint2D *vertices = geometry->vertexDataAsColoredPoint2D();
```

---

```
vertices[i].set(x, y, 0, 0, 0, 0);
//vertices[i].set(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not store multiple geometries in a geometry node. The API is very explicit about it. There's no reason to store multiple geometries there, since a node pairs a geometry and a material. You can reuse geometries and materials between nodes - that's how it's intended to be used, in fact.

The rest of the question is not really complete, and even if a shader-based implementation was provided, it won't be very useful initially. It'll be merely a premature optimization. Let's look at what you're missing.

The example BezierCurve item is just a proof of concept. It's not useful by itself, since you need a way of chaining multiple items that are stroked using the same pen. You need something akin to a simple `QPainterPath`. In fact, the geometry itself could be generated by the `QPainterPath` and `QPainterPathStroker`.

Once you've got a complete tesselated geometry for a continuously-stroked item, you can then either further cut it up based on the line style, or use a shader. It'd require profiling to show that a line-style shader by itself is a big win. It may well be that you need a geometry shader to do the stroking etc. and all the performance gain would be centered there. Think of the number of computations to be done, the line-styling is relatively simple.

Comment: Thank you. Have you got any example, which uses both - `QML` and shaders? I completely understand your answer, but I'm new to QML, so a simple example would help me much.

Answer (score -2):

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width : 1024
    height: 600

    Rectangle {
        x: -3 + 158
        y: 355
        width: 4; height: 4;
        color: "black";
        }

    Rectangle {
        x: 359 + 158
        y: 220
        width: 4; height: 4;
        color: "black";
        }

    Rectangle {
        x: 175 + 158
        y: 238
        width: 2; height: 2;
        color: "black";
        }

    Rectangle {
        x: 711 + 158
        y: 355
        width: 4; height: 4;
        color: "black";
        }

    Rectangle {
        x: 533 + 158
        y: 238
        width: 2; height: 2;
        color: "black";
        }

    Rectangle {
        x: -3 + 118
        y: 355
        width: 4; height: 4;
        color: "darkBlue";
        }

    Rectangle {
        x: 399 + 118
        y: 220
        width: 4; height: 4;
        color: "darkBlue";
        }

    Rectangle {
        x: 196 + 118
        y: 238
        width: 4; height: 4;
        color: "darkBlue";
        }

    Rectangle {
        x: 791 + 118
        y: 355
        width: 4; height: 4;
        color: "darkBlue";
        }

    Rectangle {
        x: 592 + 118
        y: 238
        width: 4; height: 4;
        color: "darkBlue";
        }


    Path {
        id: path
        startX: -3
        startY: 355
        PathQuad { x: 359; y:220; controlX: 175; controlY:238 }
        PathQuad { x: 711; y:355; controlX: 533; controlY:238 }
    }

    Path {
        id: path2
        startX: -3
        startY: 355

        PathQuad { x: 399; y:220; controlX: 196; controlY:238 }
        PathQuad { x: 791; y:355; controlX: 592; controlY:238 }
    }


    PathView {
    id: pathView;
    x: 158
    width: 708
    model: 300;
    path: path
    delegate: Rectangle {
    id: dot;
    width: 1; height: 1;
    color: "red";
    }
    }

    PathView {
    id: pathView2;
    x: 118
    width: 788
    model: 300;
    path: path2
    delegate: Rectangle {
    id: dot2;
    width: 1; height: 1;
    color: "green";
    }
    }
}
```