# How to render a cubic bezier curve in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

Out of the box you can draw Rectangles in QML. You can hack this to get a [line](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Drawing_lines_in_QML). A circle can be achieved by using rounded rects.

How can I create an Item that represents a Bezier curve, ideally a cubic one? It seems to be possible to build a carousel along a [cubic bezier path](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-pathcubic.html), but I cannot find something to get a simple bezier curve with color and thickness. Any ideas?

ps.: If the color would have a gradient I'd be more than happy, but this is only nice to have.

Comment: Did you look at this similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326037/draw-a-dashed-and-dotted-bezier-curve-in-qml ?

Comment: Yes, but this involves building a bezier curve element by hand. I was searching for a more "out of the box" solution, if available. Canvas looks like it was designed to solve my problem exactly. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Qt Quick 2, you can use Canvas item to drawing in 2D (similar to HTML 5 canvas). See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#bezierCurveTo-method